# Freeing makes things worse?

Tags: c, malloc

When I try to free an object that is malloc'd, running valgrind seems to imply I have made things worse.  For example, here is my code:

```
for(next_token = TKGetNextToken(tokenizer); next_token != NULL; next_token = TKGetNextToken(tokenizer))
        {
            ItemType* item = malloc(sizeof(ItemType));
            item->data = to_lower(next_token);
            item->fileName = filename;
            item->occ = 1;
            HM_Put(hm, item);
            free(next_token);
        }
```

Now, with the above code, I get told bytes were definitely lost on the line where item is malloc'd.  However, if I add free(item) under free(next_token), not only does that definitely lost statement remain, but I then receive a large amount of invalid reads before the heap summary. I am completely at a loss for how to fix this if anyone can provide me some help. Thanks

Comment: Adding `free` in random spots won't  fix your program. You have to think about the lifetime of each object you allocate and put your `free` accordingly. Valgrind can tell you what allocations aren't freed, but not where you should have freed them.

Comment: What is the underlying data structure of `tokenizer`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `next_token` is a string, and that `to_lower` does not create a new string. That means after freeing `next_token` the `item->data` still points to that free'd memory.

Comment: actually:
char * to_lower(char * str)
{
 char* new_str = malloc(sizeof(str)+1);
 return new_str;
}
NOTE: I omitted the non relevant parts of to_lower but I was trying to figure out how to free new_str as well.

Comment: @user2266603 Well you have *big* problem in your `to_lower` function then, as you allocate only space *for the pointer*. The `sizeof` operator will return the size of a pointer and not what it points to. Use `strlen`! That is probably the cause of your problem, as you probably overwrite beyond the end of the allocated memory and overwrite unrelated data.

Comment: 26 bytes in 6 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 9
at malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270) by: to_lower (driver.c:24)
char * to_lower(char * str)
{
 char* new_str = malloc(strlen(str)+1);

Comment: Do as @JoachimPileborg says -- use `strlen`. Your `to_lower` is flawed. My solution **will not help** against buffer overflow, and that function is setting you up exactly for that.

Comment: @user2266603 When you `free` the `item` pointer later, don't forget to `free` `item->data` first.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way of freeing the `ItemType`s *after* you close the tokenizer. If you free them before, the tokenization will read into freed memory, which is something you very much don't want to do.

I guess your framework should supply some way of freeing whatever got fed into `HM_Put`. If it doesn't, you need to do this yourself.

For example (this can be optimized by deciding which to keep between tokens and `to_lower`ed tokens):

```
typedef struct t_tofree {
    struct t_tofree *next;
    ItemType *item;
    char *token;   // Maybe superfluous if item->data points here...
};
t_tofree *toFree = NULL;

void mustFree(ItemType *item, char *token) {
    t_tofree *new = malloc(sizeof(t_tofree));
    new->next = toFree;
    new->item = item;
    new->token = token;
    toFree = new;
}

void freeAll() {
    while (toFree) {
        t_toFree *next = toFree->next;

        free(toFree->token); toFree->token = NULL;
        // The line below if token is *not* data and both were allocated.
        free(toFree->item->data; toFree->item->data = NULL;
        // Other cleanup on item?
        free(toFree->item); toFree->item = NULL;
        free(toFree); toFree = next;
    }
}
...

for(next_token = TKGetNextToken(tokenizer); next_token != NULL; next_token =     TKGetNextToken(tokenizer))
    {
        ItemType* item = malloc(sizeof(ItemType));
        item->data = to_lower(next_token);
        item->fileName = filename;
        item->occ = 1;
        HM_Put(hm, item);

        // Probably you can free next_token here, and only store item->data
        mustFree(item, next_token);
    }

 ...
 // Here you're REALLY REALLY sure you won't use tokens or items
 // (it's agreed that TKGetNextToken returns alloc'ed memory)
 freeAll();
```